# matplotlib: place axes relative to other axes, with automatic updating

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib has well documented methods of how to place multiple sets of axes in a figure window, but I cannot figure out how to define the position of one set of axes relative to the position of another set of axes.  For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    

#Define data
x1 = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y1 = np.sqrt(x1)
x2 = x1
y2 = 1.0/2.0 * x2**2.0

#Generate vertically stacked plots
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(x1,y1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(x2,y2)
fig.savefig('nice_stacked_plots.png')
```

gives the following plot:

[image: nice_stacked_plots]

This is all well and good, but when I change the size of the bottom axes

```
#Change the size of the bottom plot
bbox2 = ax2.get_position()
ax2.set_position([bbox2.x0, bbox2.y0, bbox2.width, bbox2.height * 1.25])
ax2.set_ylim(0,60)
fig.savefig('overlapping_stacked_plots.png')
```

the bottom axes overlap with the top axes

[image: overlapping_stacked_plots]

I realize I could subsequently update the position of the top axes to remove the overlap, but I would like to just specify the top axes position relative to the bottom axes at the outset, and have things automatically update.

For example, in the [annotate tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html) it is possible to place an annotation and then place a 2nd annotation at a specified offset from the 1st annotation using the `OffsetFrom` class.  If the 1st annotation moves, then the 2nd annotation moves with it.  I would like to do something similar with axes.

Comment: I would like to know how to do this also.  I think you would need to connect an axes resize event to something that would modify the position of every other subplots ... however after reading the docs I could not find an axes resize event (only canvas resize).  So I guess you could create a subclass of axes and add the event... but I'm not that good at Python yet and don't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: Yes, I agree that something like that is needed.  Given the lack of responses here, I went ahead and submitted a feature request (Issue [#3926](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3926)) on the matplotlib github page.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I have no general answer to offer, but do you know about [add_axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)?

It lets you define the location of your subplots precisely - it is then easy to make one dependent of the other.
Here is an example - as I said, pretty specific for your task, but perhaps it may inspire you?

```
# General aspect of the Fig (margins)
left = 0.1
right = 0.05
width= 1.-left-right
bottom = 0.1
top = 0.05
hspace = 0.10 #space between the subplots

def placeSubplots(fig, ax2height = (1.-top-bottom-hspace)/2.):
    ax1height = 1-top-bottom-hspace-ax2height
    ax1 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom+ax2height+hspace, width, ax1height])
    ax1.plot(x1, y1)
    ax2 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, ax2height])
    ax2.plot(x2, y2)
    return fig

fig1 = placeSubplots(plt.figure())
fig2 = placeSubplots(plt.figure(), ax2height=0.6)

fig1.savefig('fig1_equal_heigth.png')
fig2.savefig('fig2_ax2_taller.png')
```

fig1:
[image: fig1]

fig2:
[image: fig2]

Above, the second axis height is specified in an absolute way, but you could define the height of your subplots as a ratio between them too:

```
def placeSubplotsRatio(fig, ax1ax2ratio = 1.):
    subplotSpace = 1.-top-bottom-hspace
    ax1height = subplotSpace/(1.+1./ax1ax2ratio)
    ax2height = subplotSpace/(1.+ax1ax2ratio)
    ax1 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom+ax2height+hspace, width, ax1height])
    ax1.plot(x1, y1)
    ax2 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, ax2height])
    ax2.plot(x2, y2)
    return fig

fig3 = placeSubplotsRatio(plt.figure()) # idem as fig1
fig4 = placeSubplotsRatio(plt.figure(), ax1ax2ratio=3.) #ax1 is 3 times taller
fig5 = placeSubplotsRatio(plt.figure(), ax1ax2ratio=0.25) #ax2 is 4 times taller

fig4.savefig('fig4_ax1ax2ratio3.png')
fig5.savefig('fig5_ax1ax2ratio025.png')
```

fig4:
[image: fig4]

fig5:
[image: fig5]

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I am aware of `add_axes`.  As you implied, I am looking for a more robust solution than specifying the axes position and size from the outset.  I want to be able to change the position and/or size of `ax1` and have `ax2` automatically update.

Comment: OK sorry - the only way I'd see (for the moment) to do that, is to write a small function where you pass your new desired axis info as arguments (e.g., from `get_position()`+modifications as in your example) to update the other axis. And I can't really see how a built-in feature would do, beyond through a precise control of the subplots relative positions as is possible through `add_axes`. Happy to follow this question to see if an answer appears!

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, take a look at the [annotation tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).  If you use the `OffsetFrom` class, the annotation positions get automatically updated at render time, so the same thing could probably be done with axes.